# Автоматическое добавление новой записи в models Django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь реализовать такой функционал.
Есть модель Books и модель Store

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    store_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)


class Books(models.Model):
    book_name= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    book_stored_on = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    book_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Когда создаётся новая книга, допустим на одном store, я хочу что бы она создавалась и на другом store. Но, сначала, эта книга должна быть записана на первый store и только потом создалась во втором.
И при этом значение book_price для второго store менялось на противоположное значение.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # создание первой книги
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    # создание второй книги
    self.pk += 1
    if self.book_stored_on.id == 1:
        self.book_price *= -1
        self.book_stored_on.id == 2:
    elif self.book_stored_on.id == 2:
        self.book_price *= -1
        self.book_stored_on.id == 1:        
    # создание второй книги
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    # процесс выборки и отправки данных
    records = 'some data'
    return prepare_model_data(data=records)
```

Проблема в том, что просто создаётся ещё одна книга на первом сторе, а не на втором. А даже если и создаётся на втором (при условии, что добавлена 1 к book.pk), значение book_price и book_store не изменяется.

в последней строчку не указан return потому, что после сохранения записи в бд, происходит выборка всех значений из бд и отправление их в отдельную функцию, которая их обрабатывает для другого функционала.

Так же есть вопрос касательно id книги. Будет ли правильно, при её создании к id добавить 1, что бы она была записана, а не перезаписана ?

Comment: *цена умножалась на 1, что бы было положительное значение* – вероятно, опечатка. Если умножать на 1, ничего не поменяется.

Comment: нет, всё корректно. Это пример, не принимайте во внимание, что это цена. значение floatfield можно ввести отрицательное, по этому и была мысль просто умножать на 1.

Comment: Не понял Вас. Тогда это получается просто лишнее действие.

Comment: Хорошо, допустим это лишнее действие, пусть оно продолжает выполняться. Однако, как создать запись ?

Comment: А это, детектив, – правильный вопрос. (с) Я, робот :)

Comment: Я исправил вопрос, теперь это не лишнее действие ?

Comment: Чтобы умножение на единицу перестало быть лишним действием, нужно довольно глубоко укопаться в математику. К слову, теперь у Вас всегда будет отрицательная цена.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115511/discussion-between-wilteratenau-and-v-mor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто. Когда вы работаете с Django пытайтесь думать объектно, иначе зачем ещё использовать фреймворк ? :) Сей час вы меняете один и тот же экземпляр книги, а вам нужно создать ещё один и записать его в БД.

Далее псевдокод, для иллюстрации логики:

```python
if self.book_stored_on.id == 1:
    new_id = 2
elif self.book_stored_on.id == 2:
    new_id = 1
new_book = Books(
    book_name = self.book_name,
    book_stored_on = new_id,
    book_price = - self.book_price # в задаче стоит поменять цену на противоположную
) 
new_book.save()
```

P.S. Если вам нужно взять число по модулю используйте функцию abs()